# ArcGIS Javascript Api - QueryTask and setDefinitionExpression

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I've written some code to query a Feature Layer using either a QueryTask or using the setDefinitionExpression when adding the layer.

For testing I am using the ASP.Net Development Server.

I've noticed (via Fiddler) that when my "where" statement is large, my request automatically changes from a GET to a POST.  Occasionally however my request fails with an "esri.config.defaults.io.proxyUrl is not set." error.

In researching this error I have found that it may be due to the length of the URL exceeded the maximum length, and that to workaround this issue I should use a proxy, in order to perform a POST.  I am however confused by this because I am already seeing my requests change from using a GET to a POST.

When performing a query using a large where clause,does the request in fact get changed from a GET to a POST when necessary?  If so, is the use of a proxy still necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your assumption is correct.  the JSAPI switches to POST automatically when required.  If the request is interpreted as being sent to a different domain than where the application resides and either the service handling the query or browser don't support CORS, a proxy is required.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/ags_proxy.html

Comment: Interestingly I've had to revert to using a Proxy.  While using setDefinitionExpression for a Feature layer it started to fail when the query string was large.  I would see a message in the console saying that the esri.config.defaults.io.proxyUrl is not set.  Very Confusing.